# python regular expression string split

Tags: python, regex

In python, 
I have the following string:

```
|a|b\|c|d|
```

I want to split the string to:

```
a
b\c
d
```

Basically, I have to split with '|' delimiter but need to take care the backslash specially

Comment: I am novice in regex. Tried a few like: re.split('.*!\\|.*!\|', x)

Comment: Just to confirm: the backslash means "ignore the following delimiter"?  That's a little unusual -- usually it means something more like "the following character isn't being used as a delimiter", and you'd want `a`, `b|c`, `d`.

Comment: @DSM, it must be a typo. S/he probably means `b|c`, not `b\c`.

Comment: @alexis: but the OP didn't say anything about it when commenting, only "Thanks for this", not "actually, that's not want I want", and it's kind of hard to miss.  One possibility is that the OP misunderstood the problem requirements.

Comment: Yeah, that's pretty likely :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use regular expressions you need a negative lookbehind assertion.

```
import re
data = '|a|b\|c|d|'
matches = re.split(r'(?<!\\)\|', data)
```

We have to escape some special characters. The `\|` matches the single `|`. `(?<!\\)` ensures that there is no backslash before the `|`.

Now we have a leading and trailing empty string in the list. Let's use a filter to remove them.

```
filter(bool, matches)
```

Answer (score 8):

There's no need for regular expressions:

```
>>> s = '|a|b\\|c|d|'
>>> s.replace('\\|', '\\').strip('|').split('|')
['a', 'b\\c', 'd']
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I know that it doesn't need regex. But it was more for learning purpose.

Answer (score 1):

It is unclear to me if you meant `b|c` being the result of escaping `b\|c` and you have a typo? You result is non-standard since `\` is usually used to escape the splitting and keep the following delimiter.

I will assume you want the more usual `b|c` as the result in most cases.

For a regex solution, (for `b\c` in this case) this works:

```
>>> [e for e in re.split(r'\|',s.replace('\|','\\')) if e]
['a', 'b\\c', 'd']
```

I used the Python replace for the '\|' rather than the regex because it makes the regex so much easier to understand.

If you want the (what I think is more usual) `b|c` just add it back:

```
>>> [e.replace('\\','|') for e in re.split(r'\|',s.replace('\|','\\')) if e]
['a', 'b|c', 'd']
```

Or, you can use [csv](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html):

```
import StringIO
import csv

s='|a|b\|c|d|'

f = StringIO.StringIO(s)
reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter='|', escapechar='\\')

for row in reader:
    print filter(bool,row)
```

Prints:

```
['a', 'b|c', 'd']
```